# Retrieving an ASIN from Amazon and storing it in Netsuite

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, netsuite

So far I haven't been able to find out if this is possible or not but I need to make a program that allows me to enter the ASIN and then requests the pre-defined attributes associated with that ASIN from Amazon. From there I'd store them into Netsuite as an Item Record. Is this possible?

I'm worried that there might be restrictions on either the Netsuite or Amazon apis that might not let this work.

Thanks!

Comment: What information do you already have about the products on Amazon?  Where are you trying to store the information, in NetSuite?  I found an Amazon API doc (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html) that shows how to grab the ASIN.  Once received, I would just store the data in a custom field on whatever record you want.

Comment: @W3BGUY sorry I wasn't clear enough. I edited my question to better reflect what I meant to ask.

Comment: Ahh, that make sense.  You are fine on the NetSuite side.  Should be good on the Amazon side as well.  Let me take a look, and I'll update later.

Comment: Looks like the Amazon piece is defined here: DOCS: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMatchingProduct.html.  I don't have an Amazon Developer account, though.  Just create a HTTP request from a NetSutie script, process the XML response, and funnel it into a new or existing NetSuite product record.

Comment: Great, thank you! Making an HTTP request is the plan so far. I don't have a developer account either. Just out of curiosity, do you know if an account is mandatory in order to make a request? So far I haven't found out how to do it without the account...

Comment: Best I could find you have to have a developer account.  There is a free trial, though.

Comment: I figured as much. Again, thank you I appreciate the help! I will write an answer according to your info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short yes this is possible. As [@W3BGUY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611751/w3bguy) has mentioned it is definitely possible as long as you create an Amazon Developer account which has a free trial. You just have to make sure your information requests are signed and authorized correctly.

From there you make the HTTP request and then process the information into a NetSuite record.